# Simple Regex to match leading zeroes

Tags: java, regex

Am I misinterpreting something regarding Java regexes?  Shouldn't the following match the leading zero:

```
public class Testit {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        format("0115724848");
    }


    private static void format(String elementToFormat) {
        if (elementToFormat.matches("^0")) {
            System.out.println("leading zero:" + elementToFormat);
        } else {
            System.out.println("no leading zero:" + elementToFormat);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`matches` tries to match the pattern against the *whole* of the input string... and your input string isn't just "beginning of string followed by 0".

Either you need `"0.*"` (the `^` is unnecessary precisely because `matches` will match the *whole* string) or you could create a `Pattern` and then use:

```
if (pattern.matcher(text).lookingAt())
```

Of course it's not clear why you're using a regex here at all, in that you can use:

```
if (text.startsWith("0"))
```

Answer (score 4):

`String.match` wants to match the whole `String`, and your regex `^0` *doesn't*.

Instead you need a regex like: `0.*`, which means a "the string begins with 0, followed by zero or more characters". Or, depending on your needs, `0\d*`, which means "the string begins with 0 followed by zero or more digits", which is what your example input looks like.

```
if ("0115724848".matches("0\\d*"))
    System.out.println("leading zero.");
```

Comment: Thanks.  My regex testing tool indicated a match, so I thought I was done.  Looks like the match function wants me to match the entire string.

Answer (score 3):

This is the pattern that you should use:

> ^0.*

Also why not use *startsWith("0")* - much simpler

Answer (score 0):

Check this code..It should work.

```
public class Testit {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        format("0115724848");
    }


    private static void format(String elementToFormat) {
        if (elementToFormat.matches("^0.*")) {
            System.out.println("leading zero:" + elementToFormat);
        } else {
            System.out.println("no leading zero:" + elementToFormat);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex will match numbers with leading zeros, but not "0": /^0+[1-9]/